# How to remove link from around the rendered entity inside view header

Tags: views, 8

I use rendered entity inside my view header. It is a page. When the view displays, the rendered page title in the header has link around it.

I've tried to prepare my own display mode for page type of content and remove link items from them, moved them to hidden. Nothing helped.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the How:

```
 {% set headline %}
   {{ label }}
 {% endset %}
 {{ headline|striptags }}
```

as found [**here**](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2016-05-04/how-to-remove-html-markups-on-twig)

Answer (score 0):

Did you also create a new .html.twig template file that has the title without the link?

Use that new display mode, just also make sure to create a new template file: node--content-type--display-name.html.twig or whatever you need

could be in page.html.twig

Comment: I though it could be some rewrite for the field, or other trick. I may also get the page based on title criteria in other subview and add subview inside main view header. But I was wondering if there is simple solution.